# Meaning of Torsion in Chow groups

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, terminology, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading the paper "Remarks on Correspondences and Algebraic Cycles" of S. Bloch and V. Srinivas. In the proof of proposition 1 in chapter 1 says:

$Ker(CH_0(U_L))\rightarrow CH_0(U_{\Omega}))$ is torsion.

Does it mean that all the elements of the kernel are torsion or does it mean that the  kernel has some elements that are  torsion?

Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does feel more like a comment than an answer, but since this is your question:

A group is torsion, if **all** its elements have finite order.

I see no reason why we should expect a different meaning in this situation.